# Fullcalendar v5 Last hour notshowing after set slotMaxTime dinamiclly

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to add dinamiclly slotMinTime and slotMaxTime, after I do that last hour not showing. I saw in HTML its there but not showing. I try calendar.destroy  and render but nothing...you can see on image. Here is my code.. Plesase help!!!
[Last our missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dSh7.png)

```
dayCellContent: function (info) {
                if (info.view.type == "dayGridMonth") {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    var mojdatum = calendar.getDate();
                    mojdatum = moment(mojdatum).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var mojpocetak = moment(mojdatum).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
         var mojkraj = moment(mojpocetak).add("23", "h").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: TimePath,
                        data: {
                            terminal: terminal,
                            start: mojpocetak,
                            end:mojkraj,
                            tip: kupac
                        },
                        success: function (data) {                               
                            calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', data.max);
                            calendar.setOption('slotMinTime', data.min);                        
                           
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    return;
                }

            },
```

Answer (score 1):

What value did you set for `maxSlotTime` in the code which produced that screenshot?

As per the [maxSlotTime documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/slotMaxTime) it's important to remember that the time you set is **exclusive**.

So if for example you set `16.30` as the max time, it will show just like your screenshot.

Why? Because the `maxSlotTime` is treated as the moment **after** the calendar slots end. So in reality this means your calendar would end at `16:29:59`. Therefore `16.30` does not appear, because that's not part of the time period covered by the calendar.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoZaZzq

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to set manually slotMaxTime to "16:29:59" but still same think. And 16:00 also missing ..as you can see on image..Here is code

Comment: success: function (data) {

                                //var calendarOptions = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options;
                                //calendarOptions.minTime = data.min;
                                
                                calendar.setOption('slotMinTime', data.min);

                                calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', "16:29:59");

Comment: "I try to set manually slotMaxTime to "16:29:59"...why would that help?? I think you have misunderstood what I mean. If you want 16.30 to appear on the screen then you would have to set maxSlotTime to 17:00